# JavaFX MediaPlayer Error: Media invalid

Tags: javafx

I am having a problem with the JavaFX MediaPlayer. For testing purpose I downloaded the example from http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm and added some error-handling. When using the following error-handling

```
mediaPlayer.setOnError(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getError().getMessage());
    System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getError().getType());
  }
});
```

I get this console output:

```
[com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer@5482fb8f] "Error: Media invalid": "Error: Media invalid"
UNKNOWN
```

The video is encoded with h264 and aac (for audio) and is having a resolution of 1920x1168px. The error occurs with each video with a resolution greater than 1920x1080px. Vidoes with 1920x1080px or a smaller resolution are working fine. The playback of all videos is working with VLC-Player. I am using Java 7_51.

Does anybody have an idea how I could get the video running, or could it be, that videos with an higher resolution than 1920x1080px are not supported?

Comment: Try [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).  If it doesn't work [log a bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: Using Java 8 didn't solve this problem. I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you sort this, i am getting the same error being reported

Comment: I opened a bug report and switched to VLCJ.

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm) says "AAC and H.264/AVC decoding have certain platform-dependent limitations, as described in the Release Notes available at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/." Of course, every release has its own release notes, so the link from the tutorial is quite useless.  After some searching one can find  [this table for Oracle JDK 8 and JRE 8 at the end under the heading "JavaFX Media"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) (sorry, no anchors on that page), giving platform specific notes about the used implementations.  I didn't find or look for an equivalent for JDK 7, since this is a quite old question after all...

Answer (score 1):

This might have been caused by the video size.  Iirc JavaFx mediaPlayers can only play videos up to 1920x1080.  Anything noticeably larger than that will throw the Media_Invalid error.